# How to change the Boolean operators (t/f) to zeros and ones without any changing in the missing values (NaN)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert all columns in a dataframe (3700 rows x 22 columns) which including Boolean operators: true and false (t and f) to Zeros and ones with ignoring the missing values. Please note that I read the data from csv file.

For Example:

```
df = 

   X1       X2       X3    X4

 3030       f        t     a

 3456       t       NaN    b

 3567       f        f     a

 4568       f        t     b
```

After running this code:

```py
feat_cols = []

for col in df.columns:

    feat_cols.append (col)

print (feat_cols) 

for feat in feat_cols:

    if ((df[feat]=='f')).any():
       df[feat] = 
       np.where(df[feat]=="f","False",df[feat])
    if ((df[feat]=='t')).any():
        df[feat] = 
        np.where(df[feat]=="t","True",df[feat])

for feat in df.columns:

    if feat != 'True' and feat!= 'False': 

        df_Dummies = pd.get_dummies(df,dummy_na=True)
```

I got this dataframe:

```
df = 

   X1       X2_False   X2_True      X3_False  X3_True   X3_NaN    X4_a   X4_b    
 
 3030          1         0            0          1        0        1      0 
 
 3456          0         1            0          0        1        0      1

 3567          1         0            1          0        0        1      0

 4568          1         0            0          1        0        0      1
```

and this is the output which I am looking for:

```
df = 

   X1       X2          X3      X4_a    X4_b

 3030       False      True      1       0 

 3456       Ture       NAN       0       1

 3567       False      True      1       0

 4568       False      True      0       1
```

I need your help in what should I change in the code above to get the dataframe above.

Comment: I tried to use this line code, but the "X1" and "X3" has been split into other columns when I tried to use "df_Dummies = pd.get_dummies(training_data,dummy_na=True)" to the other variables (X4, X5 and etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the `boolean` dtype with its three states (True, False, NA) and take advantage of boolean masks?

```
b_cols = [col for col in df if set(["f", "t"]).intersection(df[col].unique())]
d_cols = df.select_dtypes("object").columns.difference(b_cols).tolist()
```

```py
df[b_cols] = df[b_cols].replace({"f": False, "t": True}).astype("boolean")
print(df)

     X1     X2     X3 X4
0  3030  False   True  a
1  3456   True    NaN  b
2  3567  False  False  a
3  4568  False   True  b


df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=d_cols)
print(df)

     X1     X2     X3  X4_a  X4_b
0  3030  False   True     1     0
1  3456   True    NaN     0     1
2  3567  False  False     1     0
3  4568  False   True     0     1
```

Comment: I made some few changes in my question to be more clear. Please have a look to my question again. Thanks

Comment: Column names are hard-coded to simplify the answer and highlight main functions.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use for-loop instead of specifying the column names. I have 22 variables so it is better to use for-loop. I tried this could, but it doesn't work: for feat in feat_cols:
    if ((df[feat]=='f')).any():
        df.update(df[feat].replace({"f": False, "t": True}).astype("boolean"))
    df_Dummies = pd.get_dummies(df,dummy_na=True)

Comment: Could you please inform me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) with parameter `na_action="ignore"`:

```
df.loc[:, "X2":] = df.loc[:, "X2":].applymap(
    lambda x: int(x != "f"), na_action="ignore"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     X1  X2   X3
0  3030   0  1.0
1  3456   1  NaN
2  3567   0  0.0
3  4568   0  1.0
```

Comment: I made some few changes in my question to be more clear. Please have a look to my question again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df[feat] = np.where(df[feat]=="f",0,1)
```

this last line is changing f to 0 and everything else into 1 that includes t and NaN
I would use two lines of code: (one for f and one for t)

```
df[feat] = np.where(df[feat]=="f",0,df[feat])
df[feat] = np.where(df[feat]=="t",1,df[feat])
```

Comment: I tried to use this line code, but the "X2" and "X3" has been split into other columns when I tried to use "df_Dummies = pd.get_dummies(training_data,dummy_na=True)" to the other variables (X4, X5 and etc) which include some special characters (strings)

Comment: I made some few changes in my question to be more clear. Please have a look to my question again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're using np.where,both the t values and NAN values are falling in the else statement and hence the issue, you could use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead:

```
df[feat] = np.select([df[feat]=="f", df[feat]=="t", df[feat].isnull()], [0,1,np.nan])
```

Another alternative would be to use .loc:

```
df[feat].loc[df[feat] == 'f'] = 0
df[feat].loc[df[feat] == 't'] = 1
```

And if you want to use np.where, then use it twice as has already been mentioned in another answer:

```
df[feat] = np.where(df[feat]=="f",0,df[feat])
df[feat] = np.where(df[feat]=="t",1,df[feat])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[["x2", "x4"]] *= 1
```

Python considers boolean values (True, False) like (1, 0) respectively. So you can operate with it like numbers.